# Rearrange array in jquery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem currently i do following

Html

```
<input type="text" name="Answers[0]" class="ahsan required" ><a href="#">Remove</a>
<input type="text" name="Answers[1]" class="ahsan required" ><a href="#">Remove</a>
<input type="text" name="Answers[2]" class="ahsan required" ><a href="#">Remove</a>
<input type="text" name="Answers[3]" class="ahsan required" ><a href="#">Remove</a>
<input type="text" name="Answers[4]" class="ahsan required" ><a href="#">Remove</a>
<input type="text" name="Answers[5]" class="ahsan required" ><a href="#">Remove</a>
```

above inputs are dynamically generated and obviously if user can add row then he can also delete row but if he delete row from center and submit form i am unable to get all text boxes value in array . Now i want that when i click on remove of any text box then text box gets remove but also all remaining text boxes should reordered . Can i do this Please help me . Thanks in advance

Comment: Try this one http://jsfiddle.net/FfFT9/

Answer (score 1):

unless yo're using it numeric indexes for other purposes, just try to remove them from name, having rows like

```
<input type="text" name="Answers[]"...
```

so there's no need to reorder your inputs. You should be also able to get an array on server-side processing

otherwise everytime you update the DOM use something like

```
$(".ahsan").each(function(i){
    $(this).attr({name : "Answer[" + i + "]"});
})
```

Comment: i can't dude because jquery validation is running and these counters are for jquery because if i have same name jquery will only validate one textbox and say your form is valid ...... Any other idea?

Comment: @AhsanAshfaq , see yorgo answer or a simplified version of that code in my update

Answer (score 0):

```
function reArrangeItems(){
    var i = 0;
    $(".ahsan").each(function(){
       $(this).attr({name : "Answer[" + (i++) + "]"});
    })
}
```

call this function after insert and delete

Comment: it should be `$(this).attr({name : "Answer[" + (i++) + "]"});` ? Besides, you can also use `each` iterator with `.each(function(i){ .. `

Comment: @Yorgo and Fabrizio.........Dudes  really really very thanks this one solve my problem . I am really very thankful to both of you